# How to convert textField.text value to Integer and sum two Integers

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, xcode7, calculator

> Initialization of immutable value 'textfieldInt' was never used;
>   consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it  and
>   textfield2Int

I get that warning twice for textfieldInt

This is all the code I have:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var output: UILabel!

    @IBAction func calculate(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let textfieldInt: Int? = Int(textField1.text!)
        let textfield2Int: Int? = Int(textField2.text!)
        let convert = textField1.text! + textField2.text!
        let convertText = String(convert)
        output.text = convertText

}
```

Answer (score 11):

You are receiving the warning because, as the warning tells you, you are instantiating `textfieldInt` and `textfield2Int`, but you're not using your created Integers `textfieldInt` and `textfield2Int` to be calculated as `let convert`, but you add the Strings `textField1.text!` and `textField2.text!` together...

I guess, you want your function to be that:

```
@IBAction func calculate(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let textfieldInt: Int? = Int(textField1.text!)
    let textfield2Int: Int? = Int(textField2.text!)
    let convert = textfieldInt + textfield2Int
    let convertText = String(convert)
    output.text = convertText
}
```